# What is the definition of a 'list' in python?

Tags: python, list

I always use lists when coding but can never put into words when analyzing my own work. what is the definition of a list in detail?

Comment: A sequence of things.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type).  What part of that encyclopedia level definition is insufficient?

Comment: As defined in the documentation, list is a mutable [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list), as documented in [Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

Comment: @Rejected he might not have known "list" and "array" were synonymous

Comment: You can read the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c) for it if you want to get super-specific. It's a variable-length, resizable array of pointers to arbitrary PyObjects.

Answer (score 2):

It's a datatype that stores a bunch of stuff. The more general term is an 'array.'

In python, they are represented like so:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'elem5', ['sub-list-item-1', 'sub-list-item-2'], {}]
```

One important aspect of lists is that they can contain *any* type of data, or mixed data types.

Python docs define a list thusly:

> list
>
> A built-in Python sequence. Despite its name it is more akin to
> an array in other languages than to a linked list since access to
> elements are O(1).

[Read More Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=data%20structures)